# Joint Probability and Intersection Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given two independent events A and B:

$P(A \cap B)= P(A)*P(B)$

but then I saw somewhere that:

$P(A \cap B)= P(A)*P(B)= P(A|B)*P(B) = P(B|A)*P(A)$

where for example $A$ is $X=x$ and $B$ is $Y=y$ with $X,Y$ two random discrete variables.

How can we explain the fact that $P(A \cap B)= P(A)*P(B)= P(A|B)*P(B)$ ?

Comment: $P(A \cap B)= P(B|A) \cdot P(A)$ in general but when A and B are independent then $P(B|A) = P(B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just the formula for conditional probability: $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, as long as $P(B)>0$. If you apply this formula, and then plug in the result from assuming independence, and you'll get your results.